# Request User Input Equation Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, input

I want to write a function that I can call later that allows me to request the user to input an equation. I.e. how can I have the user input something like sin(x) or exp(x^2) so that I can evaluate that function at any number of points?

I want to write the function as something like:

```
    function f = myf(x)
    f = %user enters equation%
```

Comment: Use `function handles`. Google it up.

Comment: I think I understand how to use a function handle, I'm just stuck on how to have the user input any function they choose. Would it have to be entered as a string? For instance I want to call this in another function by func('f',a,b,c)

Comment: Maybe I should edit my question. I guess I want to know how to take a string entered as 'exp(x^2)' by the user and then be able to then evaluate that at say x=5 or some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function handle:

```
function y = myf(x)

f = @(x) input('Input Equation: ');
y = f(x);

end
```

So for example:

```
>> myf(2)
Input Equation: x^2

ans =

     4

>> myf(1)
Input Equation: exp(x)

ans =

    2.7183
```

The `@(x) f(x)` is called a function handle. The input can be done using the input function. Inside input, 'Input Equation: ' is a string but when it asks you on the command line do not use a string just use the examples above.

Comment: +1, but `f = f(x);` is seriously confusing. At first, `f` is defined as a function handle (`f = @(x) ...`) and then the function is executed (`f(x)`). The confusing thing is that output value (a numeric scalar) overwrites the handle with `f = f(x);`. Why not use a different variable for either the handle or the output? Just for sake of clarity.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I edited my post for better clarity, using the f = f(x), can be confusing and sloppy coding. Thank you for the comment!